# How to hide input() in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

After pressing enter the input stays there.For example:

```
myName = input()
print("My name is:" + myName)
```

and output would be:

```
Alex
My name is:Alex
```

But I want to display only the latter.I tried using getpass but it it necessary to show the text while typing and getpass hides it.What can I do ?

Comment: A workaround would be to simply make `My name is:` the prompt: `myName = input("My name is:")`.

Comment: @chepner I mean, that solves the example, but not the general case.

Comment: So you want to type without seeing what you type. Right?

Comment: Do you want to _remove_ the first line _after_ getting the input? You must you [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) or a similar library.

Comment: The general case involves using a library to control the terminal, which is probably more complicated than it is worth.

Answer (score 5):

```
import sys

myName = input()

sys.stdout.write("\033[F") # Cursor up one line

print("My name is:" + myName)
```

Comment: This only works if one is writing to a window that imitates an ANSI/VT100 terminal.

Answer (score 3):

```
import getpass

password = getpass.getpass("Entering password: ")

print(password)
```

As written in the documentation, https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html the built-in module `getpass` provides two functions. One of them is `getpass.getpass()` which prompt the user for a password without echoing it.

Comment: did it work for you too?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This code actually worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on platform, you can move the cursor up a line before printing:

```
myName = input()
print("\x1B[F\x1B[2K", end="")
print("My name is:" + myName)
```

The middle line moves thw cursor up and clears that line in POSIX terminals.

On Windows, it's getting more complicated and you need some libraries to call Windows APIs to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

put both statements into one!

```
myName = input("My Name is: ")
```

This way, "My name is Alex" will be printed for Alex input. Also, Alex is assigned to "myName".

EDIT: Obviously, this is only a workaround and does not answer your question specifically.